# Squash migrations in Django

Tags: django

I'm quite new to Django, I have some 30 migration files and squashed last 6 migration files into 1 migration file. Now that I have squashed migrations into one file, can I delete the old 6 migration files?

Answer (score 0):

The [squash documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) is pretty clear about this, emphasis mine:

> These files are marked to say they replace the previously-squashed migrations, so they can coexist with the old migration files, and Django will intelligently switch between them depending where you are in the history. If you’re still part-way through the set of migrations that you squashed, it will keep using them until it hits the end and then switch to the squashed history, while new installs will use the new squashed migration and skip all the old ones.
>
> This enables you to squash and not mess up systems currently in production that aren’t fully up-to-date yet. **The recommended process is to squash, keeping the old files, commit and release, wait until all systems are upgraded with the new release (or if you’re a third-party project, ensure your users upgrade releases in order without skipping any), and then remove the old files, commit and do a second release.**

So keep the non-squashed files until all environments have been updated and migrated, then delete them.